# SQLite not importing text document properly

Tags: sqlite, text, import

I'm not sure if anyone has faced this issue.

Basically I have a text document with about 100,000 lines and I am trying to import it into an SQLite table with a single column.

After doing so, when I did a generic query `SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE "%something%"`, I realised that irrelevant results were turning up. Digging further, the reason was that some of the lines in the original text file got concatenated into giant row entries. This gives the impression of a wrong result (which was simply due to the giant rows having a match). Instead of 100,000 records, I had only 50,000 odd and 2 records with `LENGTH(field)` > 1,000,000 characters.

The first thing that came to my mind was the possibility of special characters messing things up, so I did a `strings FILE` in BASH. The problem persisted.

So, long story short, does anyone know the reason for this (and how to solve the issue)? Considering that the table has a single field, I don't think delimiters have anything to do with this right?

Comment: How did you import that document?

Comment: That command is intended for .CSV files. Anyway, your text file apparently does not have correct line end markers.

Comment: you are partly right. I've traced the issue to unbalanced double-quotes reserved for quoting strings in CSV. so if i have an open quote on one line, it will only count as a record when the next quote is found.

the line markers are fine, however.

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've traced the issue to unbalanced double-quotes reserved for quoting strings in csv. so if i have an open quote on one line, it will only count as a record when the next quote is found - which can be many lines down.